# How to show the equality of two Variance Inflation Factor(VIF) definitions

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

How to show  the diagonal elements of the ${C = (X'X)^{-1}}$ are $C_{jj} = \frac{1}{1 - R_{j}^2}$

where $R_{j}^2$ is the coefficient of multiple determinations from the regression of $x_j$ on the remaining p-1 regressor variables.